# reducing the build time of an angular project with more than 3000 components in my application

Tags: angular, build, production-environment

**I want to reduce the build time for my angualar project. I have more than 3000 components present in my application.

console output:

```
chunk {core.module} core.module.chunk.js () 69.9 MB  [rendered]
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.76 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 1 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {scripts} scripts.bundle.js (scripts) 872 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 680 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 13.8 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

Comment: You need to add lazy loading in your angular application: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

Comment: I'm really curious about what's going on in that core module? Did you import everything in a single module? As the others have stated, you need to split your code into modules.

Comment: Yes, all the components are imported in core.module and no lazy loading is there

Comment: Any other thing that can be added in angular.json? so that I can reduce the building time in production as build time is now taking more than 45 minutes to 2 hour.

Answer (score 1):

That's the really big problem. You need to implement different technologies.

1. Lazy Load your modules
2. Enable strict mode
3. Optimize your code, modularity and so on.

All depends on you.